# Is there a general way to tell the number of parameters of a function in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, types, parameters, functional-dependencies

I can tell the number of parameters of a function with the following code

```
{-#Language MultiParamTypeClasses#-}
{-#Language FunctionalDependencies#-}
{-#Language UndecidableInstances#-}

data Zero
data Succ a

class Number a
instance Number Zero
instance (Number a) => Number (Succ a)

class NotFunction a
instance NotFunction Int
instance NotFunction Float
instance NotFunction (IO a)

class (Number n) => FunctionLevel f n | f -> n where
  functionLevel :: f -> n
instance FunctionLevel Int Zero where
  functionLevel = undefined
instance FunctionLevel Float Zero where
  functionLevel = undefined
instance FunctionLevel (IO a) Zero where
  functionLevel = undefined
instance FunctionLevel Double Zero where
  functionLevel = undefined
instance (FunctionLevel f' n) => FunctionLevel (a->f') (Succ n) where
  functionLevel = undefined
```

And we get:

```
*Main> :t functionLevel (undefined::a->b->Int)
functionLevel (undefined::a->b->Int) :: Succ (Succ Zero)
*Main> :t functionLevel (undefined::a->b->Double)
functionLevel (undefined::a->b->Double) :: Succ (Succ Zero)
*Main> :t functionLevel (undefined::a->b->c->d->IO a)
functionLevel (undefined::a->b->c->d->IO a)
  :: Succ (Succ (Succ (Succ Zero)))
*Main> :t functionLevel (undefined::a->b->c->d->Int)
functionLevel (undefined::a->b->c->d->Int)
  :: Succ (Succ (Succ (Succ Zero)))
```

As you can see, `functionLevel` performs just as we expected for functions "ended" with some special types. My question is: could we generalize this to tell parameter number of an arbitrary function?

Comment: Yes: `functionLevel _ :: Succ Zero`, since Haskell only has one-argument functions.

Comment: If you don't like that definition, then you should explain what "parameter number" means. How many arguments does `id` have, for instance?

Comment: @shachaf Pardon, I made a silly mistake. To tell the number of a parameters of a function whose "last result" is polymorphic is certainly nonesense. But to tell that of a function with concrete "last result" is sensible.

Comment: do you want this to extend to functions that are meant to return other functions?

Comment: @JustinL. Possibly not. I am talking about something on typelevel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just an idea; you can tell the number of parameters of a function at value level with the following code.

https://gist.github.com/nushio3/5867066

```
import Data.Typeable
import Test.Hspec

arityOf :: Typeable a => a -> Int
arityOf x = go $ typeOf x
  where
    go tr
      | isFun $ typeRepTyCon tr = 1 + go (last $ snd $ splitTyConApp tr)
      | otherwise               = 0

    funTyCon = typeRepTyCon $ typeOf ((1+):: Int -> Int)
    isFun = (funTyCon ==)

main :: IO ()
main = hspec spec

func :: (Int -> Int) -> Int -> Int
func = undefined

spec :: Spec
spec = describe "arityOf" $ do
  it "evaluates Integers correctly" $ arityOf (1::Int) `shouldBe` 0
  it "evaluates Strings correctly" $ arityOf "(1::Int)" `shouldBe` 0
  it "evaluates monads correctly" $ arityOf main `shouldBe` 0
  it "evaluates multiplications correctly" $ arityOf ((*) :: Int -> Int -> Int)
    `shouldBe` 2
  it "is not deceived by non-tail argument" $ arityOf func `shouldBe` 2
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You gives me another way to look at things about typelevel.

Answer (score 0):

I found one way with type families, which works in GHC 7.6.1. It is a bit of a hack, though, since the problem of deciding what is the "ending type" is solved by marking it with a wrapper:

```
-- requires GHC.TypeLits, DataKinds, TypeFamilies and so on
newtype V a = V { unV :: a }

type family GetF f :: Nat
type instance GetF (V s) = 0
type instance GetF (a -> b) = 1 + (GetF b)

data Forget (x :: k) -- for showing types of kind Nat
```

which gives

```
*Main> :t undefined :: Forget (GetF (Int -> (Char -> Char -> V Bool)))
undefined :: Forget (GetF (Int -> (Char -> Char -> V Bool)))
  :: Forget Nat (1 + (1 + (1 + 0)))
```

But I think the problem could really be solved with [closed type families](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/GHC/Indexed_types#Family_declarations_2), which seem to come up in one of the next versions. Now, I've just read about their existence in the given link, but

```
type family GetF' f :: Nat where
  GetF' (a -> b) = 1 + (GetF' b)
  GetF' a = 0
```

looks like it should work. True pattern matching on types, finally! (And if this is nonsense, I would be really interested in some more explanation about them.)